# Extract 2 sets of numbers from string

Tags: python, regex

I have a tricky python reg ex question I am not able to solve:

`'alabama_bal_188321000_2000_name_variable_nmr_sw.csv'`

I need to process strings like the one above and extract the 2 numbers separately: `188321000` and `2000`. It is possible that there are 0 or more underscores before the 9 digit number (`188321000` in this case). Also, the length of text after `2000` is variable.

Essentially I want to extract the 2 set of numbers in that string.

Comment: Should be `r'^.*(\d+)_(\d+)'`, no?

Comment: Or, if it will always be 9 and 4-digit numbers: `r'^.*(\d{9})_(\d{4})'`

Comment: thanks @Austin, I will accept as answer. it works

Comment: `r'^.*(\d+)_(\d+)'` won't work, use `re.search(r'(\d+)_(\d+)', s)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

Code:

```
import re

regex = r"-?\d+"

test_str = "'alabama_bal_188321000_2000_name_variable_nmr_sw.csv'"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    matchNum = matchNum + 1

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

Results:

```
Match 1 was found at 13-22: 188321000
Match 2 was found at 23-27: 2000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
m = re.search('(\d+)_(\d+)', your_string)
print(m.group(1), m.group(2))
```

This outputs:

```
188321000 2000
```